# How to plot the best fit line in Python

Tags: python, plot, curve-fitting

I'm really confused :I ....
I have a ton of data and I'm trying to plot it with a best fit line.
I tried two different ways:

```
pl.plot(med[::skip],var[::skip],'k.')
p, q = np.polyfit(var[::skip],med[::skip], 1)
pl.plot(med,p*med+q,'-')
```

and

```
pl.plot(med[::skip],var[::skip],'k.')
p = np.polyfit(var[::skip],med[::skip], 1)
fit = np.polyval(p, var[::skip])
pl.plot(var[::skip],fit)
```

but they both give me something crazy:

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy.polyfit()` takes `x` then `y` as its arguments, so you need to swap `var` and `med` in your calls of it.

Note that because you have a log-log plot, this won't give you a straight line. Instead, you should fit to the log of the two variables:

```
pl.plot(med[::skip],var[::skip],'k.')
p, q = np.polyfit(np.log10(med[::skip]),np.log10(var[::skip]), 1)
pl.plot(med[::skip],10**(p*np.log10(med[::skip])+q),'-')
```

Comment: that still doesn't give me one straight line :( just some scribble

Comment: Are you using the first or the second method?

Comment: second. I tried using the first, but got  "OverflowError: Allocated too many blocks"

Comment: Well, you won't get a straight line anyway, because you have a log log plot.

Comment: i don't understand ... can one not fit a log-log plot?

Comment: Yes (although the relationship is between the logs).